# How to get pod's TCP or WebSocket connection count on Google Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-stackdriver

Is there any way to get pod's TCP or WebSocket connection count on Google Kubernetes Engine?
My point is, i need to create and scale new pod instance if my pod's connection count (not request) is over 2000?
I read GKE's and Google StackDriver's documents but there is no info about connection count.

Answer (score 0):

According to [autoscaling metrics documentation for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/external-metrics-autoscaling#using_a_different_metric), any Stackdriver metric can be used for auto scaling as long as metricType = INT64 or DOUBLE.

Saying this, there are currently no GCP [Stackdriver metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp) in that table that can scale depending on connection or websockets.

To do what you want, you can look into Autoscaling with [custom metrics](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/custom-metrics-autoscaling#choosing_a_custom_metric).